# Java: Actions as objects? Inheriting exception handlers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command

I'm new to the "command" software design pattern, and I attempted it without really knowing what I was doing. I understand that this isn't exactly an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, but if you look at my source, does it look like I'm approaching it right? I've made objects that perform their task as they're constructed (while the super class handles any raised exceptions.)

(Edit #1: this source is within another class, one whose fields include "out" and "in".)

```
public static interface Operations{
        public void action(String filename)
            throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException;
    }

    public static abstract class Operator implements Operations{
        public Operator(String filename){
            try{
                action(filename);
            } catch(FileNotFoundException FNFE){
                sessionLog.report(FNFE.toString());
            } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException UEE){
                sessionLog.report(UEE.toString());
            } catch(IOException IOE){
                sessionLog.report(IOE.toString());
            } finally{

                try{
                    out.close();
                } catch(IOException IOE){
                    sessionLog.report("The file may not have closed properly. "+IOE.toString());
                } catch(NullPointerException NPE){
                    //sessionLog.report("The file may be null.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Saver extends Operator{
        public void action(String filename) 
                throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), ENCODE);
            out.write("Spoons.");
        }
        public Saver(String filename){super(filename);}
    }

    public static class Opener extends Operator{
        public void action(String filename) 
                throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{

            in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), ENCODE);
            /* ... */
        }
        public Opener(String filename){super(filename);}
    }

    public static void save(String filename, ShoppingMutableTreeNode SMTN){
        new Saver(filename);
    }

    public static void open(String filename){
        new Opener(filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation looks fine to me.  A couple of suggestions though:

I would get rid of the filename parameter to action(), as it would let me do something like

```
 new Saver("file1.txt").action("file2.txt");
```

I would also get rid of the action() call in the constructor.  I don't think most developers would deduce that the constructor was performing the actual action without digging into your source - it just doesn't seem intuitive.  Something like this would be more explicit:

```
 public abstract class Operation implements ... {
    private String filename;

    public Operation(String filename) { this.filename = filename; }

    public abstract void execute();
 }
```

Then your code could invoke it

```
 new SaveAction("myfile.txt").execute();
```

One last quick word on Command pattern - you are using it here to share exception handling.  That really reminds me more of the [Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

The power of the pattern really comes from the fact that you have abstract actions and execute them without knowing what exact action it is at runtime.  Here are some uses for the pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Uses